# Get "Access to OData is disabled" error only on a specific user

Tags: oauth-2.0, microsoft-graph-api

I've create an app on microsoft azure portal and i created a c# application who read the number of email's inside inbox folder of a user (using Microsoft Graph).
It works correctly with every user except one.
With that user i get "Access to OData is disabled"
How it's possibile? the api abilitations of the applications are activated (Mail.Read)
[image]

Answer (score 0):

API call is [denied access](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-limit-mailbox-access#handling-api-errors) due to a configured application access policy for specific user.

Administrators can create an application access policy to limit third-party app access to only set of mailboxes.

Administrator for your organization must ensure that your app has permission to access the mailbox of the specific user.